# typo3 Powermail "required argument mail is not set" with redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, typo3

I have some redirects in my `.htaccess-file`. One of them is the simple redirect from non-www to www.

I wrote it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.org$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, when this rule is active and I submit a form on my page, I get the following error:

*required argument mail is not set*

Without the rule, everything works as expected. Is my RewriteCond / Rule wrong? 
If you need further information, just tell me.

Typo3 6.2.12 on PHP 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The `base`-url was set to non-www. After changing that to `www.example.org`, everythings works fine again. (Even with the htaccess rules).

Comment: So you meant TypoScript config.baseURL? (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#baseurl) Maybe clarify that in the answer ...